# Subversion -- switch to previous branch

Tags: svn

I find myself typing `svn switch ^/trunk` and `svn switch ^/branches/myBranch` a lot.  Is there a way in svn to switch to the previous branch I was on?  For example:

```
svn switch ^/trunk
svn switch ^/branches/myBranch
svn switch --last (switches back to trunk)
svn switch --last (switches back to mybranch)
```

It would be sort-of like pushd.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a proxy around svn that records switch values and handles flips...

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $1 == "flip" ]]; then

    if [[ ! -e ~/.svnswprev1 ]]; then
        echo "Danger Will Robinson!"
        exit 1
    fi

    read p < ~/.svnswprev1
    mv ~/.svnswprev0 ~/.svnswprev1
    echo $p > ~/.svnswprev0

    exec /usr/bin/svn switch "$@" "$p"
fi

if [[ $1 != "switch" ]]; then

    exec /usr/bin/svn "$@"

fi

if [[ -e ~/.svnswprev0 ]]; then

    mv ~/.svnswprev0 ~/.svnswprev1

fi

echo ${@: -1} > ~/.svnswprev0

exec /usr/bin/svn "$@"
```

*note - svnswprev should probably be scoped to repository*

Comment: I got a svn error when I tried this; it says `type 'svn help' for usage`.

Comment: @AlexMA Updated the code.  It should be fairly easy to adapt to your needs.

Comment: I will test this tomorrow! It looks more promising.